How do I use a model that can be loaded with AutoModelForSequenceClassification with AutoModelForTokenClassification for Ner fine tuning?
While I can fine tune the BERT model with the custom data in the specific domain by loading it with AutoModelForTokenClassification, I can load another BERT model trained in that domain only with AutoModelForSequenceClassification and as a result I get a tensor shape error. If this is the case, how can I perform fine tuning using AutoModelForSequenceClassification?
The size of tensor a (716) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1
